# Shortcut key to open YouTube videos in full screen mode

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

What keyboard shortcut will open up full screen mode while playing YouTube videos?

Viewing on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 25):

If the YouTube video is the active part of the screen, <kbd>F</kbd> seems to work for me.

Comment: +1 Yes, this works for me. However, I would stress **active part of screen** as it often isn't. It doesn't appear to receive focus by tabbing, so it might only be **active** if you have literally just clicked on it (Play or Pause).

Comment: I can't up-vote StlrFan's answer but the `F` key is the only shortcut that I know of. Interacting with the flash player is really terrible. Once it's focused I don't think you can get focus back to your browser without clicking outside flash and the opposite is also true, you can't grab flash focus unless you click it... I sure am glad it's dying...

Comment: Works for me, if I am focussed on the page, but not the video. Still thank you!

Answer (score 7):

While not a simple shortcut, there are several ways to achieve fullscreen play without a mouse:

1. Visit https://youtube.com/html5 and opt-in to the experiment.
   After that most (but not all) youtube videos will use the native `<video>` tag instead of Flash, with a slightly different UI.  The fullscreen control *is* reachable in this UI by pressing (quite a lot) <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
2. Edit the URL (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) from `https://youtube.com/watch?v=t9HMeYs2Yas` form to `http://youtube.com/v/t9HMeYs2Yas` form.
   This will give you the player filling the whole browser window; you can now press <kbd>F11</kbd> to really go full screen (being browser fullscreen, it behaves better than Flash fullscreen, especially with multiple monitors).

   A major drawback is that you're trapped into that one video — no access to comments, related videos, search etc.
3. Edit the URL to `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch?v=t9HMeYs2Yas` form (if you're signed in you can just visit https://youtube.com/tv, navigate Up to My Watch History and press Enter to open your last video).
   **This is by far the most keyboard-friendly way to consume youtube.**

   - The player fills the window (<kbd>F11</kbd> to really go full screen).
   - Press <kbd>Up</kbd> to access the player controls — pause (<kbd>Space</kbd>), seek (<kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd>), captions etc.
   - Press <kbd>Down</kbd> for navigation menu — doesn't interrupt the fullscreen video!
   - Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close controls/menu and get the clean player back.

   Drawbacks:

   - I didn't find any way to read comments (some would call this a blessing ;-).
   - You can't manually control the video quality.  It's always "auto".

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in keyboard shortcut for going full screen on Youtube.
This is the current list of [shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=189278).

Comment: 'F' key works for me. I have tested in Chrome in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>F11</kbd> it will display the video in full screen and when you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> it will change it back to normal size.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some indication that pressing F should switch to full-screen mode, but http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/comprehensive-guide-youtube-player-keyboard-shortcuts/ states that it doesn't work for everyone. Didn't work for me, anyway.

Comment: The **"F" key** didn't work for me as well

Comment: I think the **F** key is for embedded videos.

Comment: 'F' key works for me. I have tested in Chrome in Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out these links and create your full screen YouTube launcher.

http://www.gwenael.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=193

https://superuser.com/questions/430862/windows-launch-google-chrome-in-fullscreen-mode

Comment: please include more information, summarize what needs to be done. have a look at this: [Policy about link as answer](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/442/policy-about-link-as-answer/443#443)

Answer (score -1):

It’s quite simple, just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.